# Can't open InstallShield 2013 project with InstallShield limited edition 2015 - what can I do?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installshield

I have an InstallShield project that was created using InstallShield 2013 and I don't have access to that version of InstallShield. I just downloaded the free (limited) version of InstallShield 2015 and I can't load my project. I've compared the source of my installer project to that of one created using the 2015 version and I even tried changing everything in the file so that it's exactly the same as the 2015 file and I still get "This version of Visual Studio is unable to open..."

Here's the compare of the two files. The one on the right opens fine, but the one on the left doesn't:

[image]

Here's the two files after being made the same:
[image]

And here's the error I get when I try to load the file:
[image]

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio are you using? InstallShield 2015 LE does not support the community edition of Visual Studio.

Comment: VS 2013 Ultimate.